# Moving a point a specified distance and bearing in QGIS

Tags: qgis, editing

I need to move a point feature a specified distance and direction.

In ArcMap I would select the point in an edit session and go to the edit menu and choose "Move" then it pops up a dialog box to enter the distance to move and at what azimuth.

I am looking for something similar in QGIS but so far all the answers I have come across are scripting solutions for moving large datasets.  However i just need to move a single point in a dataset and without writing python.  The "move feature" button allows me to grab it to move, but I don't want to drag it to the new location, I want to give it a numerical offset from its current location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "Move feature" in the "Advanced Digitizing" toolbar. See https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#move-feature-s

It is a bit unwieldy for your use case, in that you need to select the point feature, then click it again (with snap on) to make its current location the so-called origin point of the displacement, but then you can enter the `a`zimuth and `d`istance of the desired displacement (or `x` and `y` displacement if you prefer) in the Advanced Digitizing panel. So it is ultimately more powerful and flexible.

Comment: Thank You!  I have been playing around with how the advanced digitizing window works with this and had yet to figure it out but your instructions worked great!  You're right on the cumbersome comment, and it would be nice if the feature you have selected when clicking the "move feature" button automatically became the default point to offset without the second click, but it's not the end of the world.